# Convert Old MongoDB Update Query into New MongoDB 4.2.0 Query

Tags: mongodb

Please solve this issue.

```
public static void updateInvoice(BsonDocument query)       
{
            
try
            
{
                
var BCOldcollectionP = database.GetCollection<ukgeoJsonResults> ("BookingClosed");

                var updateValues = new List<UpdateBuilder>();
                updateValues.Add(Update.BitwiseOr("mstate", 001));
                IMongoUpdate updateMult = Update.Combine(updateValues);
                BCOldcollectionP.Update(query, updateMult, UpdateFlags.Multi);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionalHandler.ExceptionWriter(null, ex);
            }
        }
```

Error: IMongoCollection does not contain a definition for 'Update' and no accessible extension method 'Update' accepting a first argument of type 'IMongoCollection' could be found

Comment: Please tag the language you are using. I guess it is C#

Comment: Yes i'm using C#

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.